# Sencha touch 2: How to use Jquery mobile code inside Sencha touch code?

Tags: jquery-mobile, extjs, sencha-touch

I wanted to create mobile application wherein am using Sencha touch 2 framework. I need to embed Html forms created using jquery mobile in sencha touch 2 code. So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you can use [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) to build jquery applications and Sencha can be used as the v (or Viewer) portion of your application.  I'm not sure Sencha can use any portion of jquery although you can embed html, ruby and of course javascript as needed which are all pieces of jquery (minus the framework).

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question actually... Sencha touch code is simply one file that you include in your index.html file... Similarly you can add jquery mobile there as well just like you might add jquery in a normal HTML file... Although be careful how you are going to use it to work in sync with sencha...All sencha components have a html parameter so i think best strategy for you would be to create a sencha container and put your jquery content in the html parameter...Hope it works...